# unsetting custom fields in checkout - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I can unset fields from billing and shipping but why I can't unset fields from additional field section. I am adding a condition on these fields. Maybe I am using wrong meta keys.

```
function wc_remove_checkout_field( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields['billing']['test_field'] ); //this one working
    unset( $fields['additional']['delivery_time'] ); //this one not even if I replace additional with order.


    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wc_remove_checkout_field' );
```

Creating fields usings this plugin [WooCommerce Checkout Field Editor](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/checkout-field-editor/?_ga=2.172900960.2108560389.1501134995-1444052921.1497320962#prettyPhoto)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter to remove the order notes field:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false');
```

If you want to stick with your method using `unset`, you need to replace "additional" with "order":

```
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
```

Comment: this both working for me. I cannot unset those fields which which I am creating using this plugin. I'm a creating a condition based on product category in cart.

Comment: If it's plugin-related, try contact the plugin author